# Is there a way to make the javascript run through all conditionals in an if statement, even if it knows it's already wrong?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to run through a series of forms on a quiz. I need it to alert the user if they have left one of the answers out. If they have left more than one out, I need to send more than one alert.

```
function validate(){
  if ((q2Check() === true) && (q1Check() === true)){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

The code snippet above is the section that checks all the questions returning true. Currently only have 2 questions in it. The alerts are in the individual question functions. My problem is, if both questions have been left unanswered, only the q2Check alert is shown, presumably because that one is returning false so it no longer needs to check the rest of the conditions.

Is there a way to get it to check all conditions, thus bringing up all the alerts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) here.

```
if ([q2Check(),q1Check()].every(function(b){ return b; })){
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

What we are doing is, creating an Array of booleans(which means both `q1Check` and `q2Check` are called and associate alert is also alerted) and then we use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which returns a boolean stating if all the members of the Array meet the required condition.

Here we just return the bool `b`, because it's either `true` or `false`.

Comment: so that basically asks, "Once ALL functions in the array return true, return true"?

Comment: @Finlay yup. That's what it does.

Comment: @Finlay there was a typo. The method is called `Array.every` not `Array.all`

Comment: would this work the same if there were 3 elements in the array

Comment: @Finlay it will work for any number of elements. Just add it to the array.